# Directional collision detection

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision-detection

If I want to move an object 40 pixels every second and I have the following scenario, how can I efficiently detect that there was a collision?

Assume both objects are 10 by 10 squares

Starting point of moving object at 2 seconds:

40, 100

Ending point of moving object at 3 seconds:

80, 100

Stagnant object at 60, 100

If I am only moving the moving object once (from 40 to 80 without any movements in between) how would I tell there was an object between them?

This is obviously a simplified version of what I am doing but I wanted it to be easy to understand.

The only thing I can think of is check if each object has a side with an x value less than 80 and another side with an x value greater than 40 and the same idea with y values...

I'll be using javascript and html5 canvas if that makes any difference.

Comment: You could always move it 4 px every .1 second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to determine if there was a collision with the bounding rectangle defined by the start and end positions of the moved object:

```
+-----------+--+
|     +==+  |  |
+-----:  :--+--+
      +==+
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like this which is already written and can handle all sorts of shapes:

http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/